# Custom Post - add new class in categories once it's active

Tags: php, categories, custom-post-type

I tried different solution from internet but it doesn't work in my code. My goal is to add "active class" in categories when it's active. here is my working code for get_categories

```
<?php
  $args = array(
   'orderby' => 'slug',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'parent' => 0,
   'hide_empty' => false
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach( $categories as $category ){
      echo '<li><a class="ctg" href="'. get_category_link( $category->term_id ) .' "><p>' . $category->name . '</p></a></li>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/ gets you the currently requested item.

Comment: @CBroe I don't understand the logic of get_queried_object from the link you provided. is there any other way?